# Cut Text Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

A few days ago I asked a question, to understand how to eliminate an annoying text effect

[image]

Thanks to 'help from other users, I am able to understand that the effect is due to an edge of the same of the background color.

It would therefore be easy to eliminate this problem, but with `border : none` property nothing happens anyway.

The link of effect codrops is: [this](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ResponsiveIconGrid/).

And a Link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5t9V/)

I hope someone can remove the effect in question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please. Post. Code. In. Your. Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to remove the underlines in your links. Try adding the following CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To remove the effect from the `cbp-ig-grid`, prepend a class name like such:

```
.cbp-ig-grid a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```